# How to make UI for different resolutions in android

Tags: android-layout

What is the best practice to set UI layout that supports all type of screen resolutions of Android (Tablet of all sizes & mobile devices of all sizes).

Answer (score 0):

most importantly , your images of app should support all screen sizes and densities, you can [read this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)